# Set boolean value in redis leads to 502 error in PHP

Tags: php, redis

Why could PHP code

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', '6379');
$redis->set("testkeybool", false);
```

lead to 502 error?

```
2018/10/30 13:59:29 [error] 23512#0: *12 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: ..., server: my.host, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "..."
```

if I set integer instad of boolean, it works OK

```
$redis->set("testkeybool", 0);
```

nginx config

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

PHP version PHP 5.6.36

Comment: Check the actual PHP error log …

Comment: also, unless this is just educational, I highly recommend running php 7+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because redis only supports the following datatypes `string, list, hash, set, sorted set, bitmaps, and hyperlogs`. When using the setter `$redis->set();` (Set key to hold the string value.) it needs to be in the form of one of those datatypes

Try

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', '6379');
$redis->set('testkeybool', 'false');
```